# SSH X11 not working

Tags: ssh, x11, x11forwarding

I have a home and work computer, the home computer has a static IP address.

If I ssh from my work computer to my home computer, the ssh connection works but X11 applications are not displayed.

In my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` at home:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

At work I have tried the following commands:

```
xhost + home HOME_IP
ssh -X home
ssh -X HOME_IP
ssh -Y home
ssh -Y HOME_IP
```

My `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` at work:

```
Host *
ForwardX11 yes 
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

My `~/.ssh/config` at work:

```
Host home
HostName HOME_IP
User azat
PreferredAuthentications password
ForwardX11 yes
```

My `~/.Xauthority` at work:

```
-rw------- 1 azat azat 269 Jun  7 11:25 .Xauthority
```

My `~/.Xauthority` at home:

```
-rw------- 1 azat azat 246 Jun  7 19:03 .Xauthority
```

**But it doesn't work**

After I make an ssh connection to home:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0

$ kate
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
kate: cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0
```

I use `iptables` at home, but I've allowed port 22.  According to what I've read that's all I need.

**UPD.**
With `-vvv`

```
...
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 1: request x11-req confirm 1
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: channel 1: request pty-req confirm 1
...
```

When try to launch `kate`:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 2 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 55486
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug2: X11 connection uses different authentication protocol.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
debug2: X11 rejected 2 i0/o0
debug2: channel 2: read failed
debug2: channel 2: close_read
debug2: channel 2: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 2: send eof
debug2: channel 2: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 2: write failed
debug2: channel 2: close_write
debug2: channel 2: output open -> closed
debug2: X11 closed 2 i3/o3
debug2: channel 2: send close
debug2: channel 2: rcvd close
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: x11, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  #1 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)
  #2 x11 (t7 r2 i3/0 o3/0 fd 8/8 cc -1)

# The same as above repeate about 7 times

kate: cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0
```

**UPD2**
Please provide your Linux distribution & version number.
Are you using a default GNOME or KDE environment for X or something else you customized yourself?

```
azat:~$ kded4 -version
Qt: 4.7.4
KDE Development Platform: 4.6.5 (4.6.5)
KDE Daemon: $Id$
```

Are you invoking ssh directly on a command line from a terminal window?
What terminal are you using? xterm, gnome-terminal, or?
How did you start the terminal running in the X environment? From a menu? Hotkey? or ?

```
From terminal emulator `yakuake`
Manualy press `Ctrl + N` and write commands
```

Can you run xeyes from the same terminal window where the ssh -X fails?

```
`xeyes` - is not installed
But `kate` or another kde app is running
```

Are you invoking the ssh command as the same user that you're logged into the X session as?
`From the same user`

**UPD3**

I also download `ssh` sources, and using `debug2()` write why it's report that version is different
It see some cookies, and one of them is empty, another is `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason ssh X forwarding wasn't working was because I have a `/etc/ssh/sshrc` config file.

The end of the `sshd(8)` man page states:

> If `~/.ssh/rc` exists, runs it; else if `/etc/ssh/sshrc` exists, runs it; otherwise runs xauth

So I add the following commands to `/etc/ssh/sshrc` (also from the sshd man page) on the server side:

```
if read proto cookie && [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
        if [ `echo $DISPLAY | cut -c1-10` = 'localhost:' ]; then
                # X11UseLocalhost=yes
                echo add unix:`echo $DISPLAY |
                    cut -c11-` $proto $cookie
        else
                # X11UseLocalhost=no
                echo add $DISPLAY $proto $cookie
        fi | xauth -q -
fi
```

And it works!

Comment: You do it on the client or on the server side?

Comment: On a server side. (/etc/ssh/sshrc executed when client is connected)

Comment: OMG!!!! Thank you so very much! I have been chasing my tail checking everything I could imagine and the sshrc file never came to mind. I don't use x11 over SSH often. Once every few YEARS maybe. Some time back I created the file /etc/ssh/sshrc (didn't exist before) to display some useful information when starting an SSH connection. Then the other day (about a year later) I needed X11 and it wouldn't work giving the error "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication". I tried everything and nothing worked until I found this fix. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Any time you're having trouble with ssh, the first thing you should do is run the client with the `-v` option to provide that output for others to inspect:

```
ssh -v user@somewhere
```

I am going to guess that the problem is on your local system. How are you invoking the ssh command? Are you running it manually in a shell? Or is it being executed as part of a script? In either case you'll want to make sure that your local system has the `DISPLAY` environment set correctly. It also needs to be set correctly on the remote side, as well, but that value *will be different* on the remote side than the local side.

From what you wrote it seems that it is being set correctly on the remote host (and by extension the X11 forwarding is being set up correctly by ssh). On the remote system you have:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

What is that showing on the local side? That should be easy to check if you're in a shell both by echoing the value, as well as starting an X app from that shell... you can always use the venerable `xeyes` for that kind of testing, of course! :)

On the other hand, if you are invoking the ssh command from a script or attached to a hotkey it might not inherit the environment that you expect, so `DISPLAY` environment variable on the local side might not be set at all.

Also, since it sounds like you've been fiddling with your `.Xauthority` file you may want to delete it entirely, then log out of your X session and log back in so it will automatically re-create it. There is rarely a need to muck with your `.Xauthority`, so trying that is likely just a desperate measure that won't help.

What you should see on the local side is:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

On a properly configure system if you open a shell you shouldn't need to set it by hand, it should get inherited from the environment that started your shell. However I have seen window manager / hotkey configs that do not properly handle environment variable inheritance. If you have linux system running `gnome-session` or `kde-session` that you use to launch your shells or scripts from, then your X session environment variables should get set correctly as described in the [Ubuntu documentation about inheritance of environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Inheritance):

> When a parent process creates a child process, for example when we run
>   the "gedit" command from the terminal and "bash" (the parent process)
>   creates "gedit" (the child process), the child process inherits all
>   the environment variables and values the parent process had.
>
> ...
>
> Note: in the Gnome graphical desktop environment, gnome-session is the
>   parent process of all the processes running on the desktop. This fact
>   (along with the Inheritance principle) is the key to our ability to
>   powerfully influence the operation of our desktop with environment
>   variables. The equivalent process in KDE is kde-session.

**UPDATED**

Thanks for posting the output from `ssh -vvv`. In this case the extra verbosity from `-vvv` versus just `-v` is helpful. The debug output tells me that X11 forwarding is being set up correctly:

```
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 1: request x11-req confirm 1
```

But the `:0` in the first line leads me to believe there is still a configuration error on the local side in the way you're invoking ssh. On many systems the default value for `DISPLAY` is `:0.0`, not `:0`. Are you somehow setting the value of `DISPLAY` manually yourself before invoking the ssh command?

More information about your local system and how you're invoking the ssh command would be helpful at this point.

- Please provide your Linux distribution & version number.
- Are you using a default GNOME or KDE environment for X or something else you customized yourself?
- Are you invoking ssh directly on a command line from a terminal window?
- What terminal are you using? xterm, gnome-terminal, or?
- How did you start the terminal running in the X environment? From a menu? Hotkey? or ?
- Can you run `xeyes` from the same terminal window where the `ssh -X` fails?
- Are you invoking the ssh command as the same user that you're logged into the X session as?

This last item is important. If you're running ssh as another user (for example, if you opened up a root terminal window instead of a user terminal window), then you'll encounter this problem even if you are explicitly setting `DISPLAY=:0` since you don't have permissions to connect to the X server by default as another user (even as root!)

Comment: Update question body

Comment: I added a new **UPDATED** section asking for more info to help debug this further.

Comment: I don`t set `DISPLAY` manualy. In fact I think that I understand why it not works, because of `X -nolisten` on local machine

Comment: `-nolisten` has nothing to do with this problem. As far as X is concerned it knows nothing about your remote ssh connection. To X it looks like any other local program.

Comment: Yes, I think like this, before I read http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X-Forwarding

Comment: I update question body - UPD2, UPD3

Comment: `sshd` can also be started in the foreground with extra verbosity in case the problem lies on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Your configs seem to be ok, but do try "ssh -X home" as Agemen suggested.

Also, if all else fails, try this:

After you ssh to your home machine from work, on "home" type:

```
xauth list
```

Then, on "work", type

```
xauth
```

Which will give you an "xauth>" prompt. From here, type "add", then copy paste the output of the "xauth list", one line at a time (each line prefaced by "add"). For example:

```
someguy@work:~$ xauth
Using authority file /var/run/gdm/auth-for-someguy-4MYV85/database
xauth> add work/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  781cc753194fd55ecdf6c4cf105c40e3
xauth>
```

Let us know.

Comment: I have already tried `ssh -X home` (write in post). About xauth I will try tomorrow.

Comment: I try `xauth list & xauth add`, but still not works

Comment: I have add this record via `xauth add` `azat/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ad01c582768c832ff591277b27863bc7` (because $DISPLAY=localhost:10.0), if this can help

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked on my MAC Running MacOS Monterey 12.2
Try this:

In the sshd_config file on the Linux server:

uncomment X11Forwarding and set it to yes on the SERVER

it should look like:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

DO NOT uncomment #X11DisplayOffet 10
DO NOT uncomment #X11UseLocalHost no

Run XQUARTZ on the MAC so that it opens a window on the MAC screen. DO NOT login using ssh in the XQUARTZ window.

Open a mac terminal window.

Login to your remote server on the MAC terminal, not the window XQUARTZ opened:

```
ssh -Y myusername@SERVER
```

then run your X11 app from the MAC terminal NOT the open XQUARTZ window.

ex:

```
xclock &
```

XQUARTZ will intercept the DISPLAY and show the app on the local e.g. terminal screen. If you export the DISPLAY to :0 the window will appear on the server side.  Not what you probably want.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand clearly if you want to display your remote apps on your local display (`work`), or if you want to display them on the remote system (`home`).

In the first case, I think `ssh -X host` should be enough, without any need to use xhost.

In the second case, the system where you need to use xhost is `home`, and it is not enough, you need to export the display variable too.

```
xhost +work
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

I'm not totally sure of what you want to do... and as I don't know what differences exist between your system and mine, on the first hand, and the exact configuration needed for you case on the other hand (as I'm not a specialist ^_^). Hope it will help you in some ways, as this too configurations have worked for me.

Comment: I have already tried `ssh -X home` (write in post). Yes I want to display remote apps on my local display.